# How to implement EntitySetController Queryable ODATA with NHibernate as ORM and handle transaction as well?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, odata

I am an experienced EF developer but newish to NHibernate.

In a MVC 4 project, the EntitySetController ODATA Queryable support is very easy to implement, and gives a lot more freedom as well.

However, it's Microsoft stack technology, EF has the best support, when I thought about replacing EF with NHibernate, I encountered the "all calls should be under a transaction in NHibernate." problem.

As ayende's blog: NH Prof Alerts: Use of implicit transactions is discouraged
http://ayende.com/blog/3775/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged

So the question is how to wrap the query in a "transaction" when using EntitySetController with NHibernate?

Code samples and articles etc, will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction()) { doSomething(); }`?

Comment: Hi @Firo, Thanks for pointing out the obvious. I am newish to NHibernate, I didn't expect this to work straight away. ... I just created a MVC project to test this thing, and it works. Doh. But how? I will create another question for that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF handles Transactions implicitly, NHibernate needs explicit code. So Each business operation (e.g. request) will have the

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    // Do something
    tx.Commit();
}
```

around it. You could implement it as Aspect in web applications in BeginHandleRequest, EndHandleRequest like methods